# GCP Monitoring can't get metrics from asia-southeast1-b

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I've several GCE instances located two zone: `asia-southeast1-b` and `us-east4-c`. All instances  have already install stackdriver agent. In metrics explorer, I can't find `asia-southeast1-b` in `CPU load` metric:

[image]

But `CPU Usage` is OK:

[image]

What's wrong with this?

Comment: click three-colum icon next to the `Value` column. Select `zone` to be shown, see if there is data for that zone in that metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this error by adding `Monitoring Metric Writer` permission to the service account.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45068262/380774

Answer (score 1):

Can you execute this command inside the VM’s deployed in asia-southeast1-b:

```
grep collectd /var/log/{syslog,messages} | tail
```

This will show if there is any error with the agent.

To my understanding, this metric (CPU Load) is recollected from Stackdriver agent, then sent to Monitoring.
Let’s see if we can understand what is happening:

- Is there a problem with Stackdriver Agent gathering that metric?
- Or is there a problem in Monitoring API while ingesting it?

Let me ask you some questions:

- Are you using different Operating Systems on the Instances on asia-southeast1-b in comparison to the one’s running in us-east4-c?
- Which version of Stackdriver are you running?
  In this link you will be able to determine which version you have installed.[2]
- Did you make any changes in the configuration of the Stackdriver agent? The file is located in /etc/stackdriver/collectd.conf

Best regards,

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#agent-version

Comment: Same OS, same agent version, but different service account with different permission caused this error. Thanks for your help.